# extracting data from various lines from text file: Python

Tags: python-2.7

hello i m new in python (have to use python 2.7) programming and i m working on a legacy system which generates a txt file of 13,000 lines and sample is as follows

```
center = 1204
blah
blah
outside_diameter = 9.00023
blah 
blah
 --- MEASUREMENT DATA LEFT ---
2.0003 , 3.000943
3.4330 , 3.00083
 --- MEASUREMENT DATA RIGHT ---
4.0054 , 2.00004
3.4343 , 3.03200
```

i have to find the values of center and outside_diameter and store that int data in variables...  then tricky part (for me)  i have to read all the lines after `--- MEASUREMENT DATA LEFT ---` line and the no of lines to be read is equal to the center's int value that is i\In this case i have to read 1204 lines after `--- MEASUREMENT DATA LEFT ---` line
similarly for the `--- MEASUREMENT DATA RIGHT ---` 
and save all these results in a text file.

kindly help with this....
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the file, you can use some [Python Input and Output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) work and some [Python string manipulation.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Tip:

```
"random" in ["just some random text"]
```

returns True;